# how to use auth0 with nativescript angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, auth0

We are currently working on nativescript angular application. We want to authorise users and grant them different permisions. So we decided to use auth0 platform to get that. But saddly we can't find any working example of how to integrate Auth0 platform into nativescript angular applications.

There is a single npm [link](https://github.com/sitefinitysteve/nativescript-auth0) to plugin that is supposed to support such integration, but this plugin is broken and there are several problematic [issues](https://github.com/sitefinitysteve/nativescript-auth0/issues/27) that we faced with and there is no support for that plugin anymore.

**Edit:**
*Our client application was developed using nativescript and angular for android and ios platforms.
Our objectives are:*

1. To authenticate the user by social media that is provided by auth0
   in the client side.
2. To get the authentication token back to the client.
3. To authorize the user by the token we got during the authentication, each time we using the server.

Can you provide a working example of how to integrate auth0 with the nativescript angular application?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @cbrawl for not is not possible.

Comment: @Ilan Does the angular-jwt flow ended up working ? I am using the new SPA Sdk and it does not work with Nativescript so far.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg don't know, for then we use another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @auth0/angular-jwt
[GitHub repo](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)

If you are on the newer Angular version using HttpInterceptor, use the v1.0 branch.

```
npm install @auth0/angular-jwt@1.0.0-beta.10
```

Instructions to use the package are in its README here:
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/tree/v1.0

Comment: thanks, will check this, please see the edited version of the question.